# Querying custom contenttype SPO data with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm very new to flows having inherited a whole ensemble of flows that were built 4+ years ago that were built to handle a customised 'Controlled Documents' review and publish approval system. Its had a lot of bugbears over the years to do with a whole smorgasbord of different causes, some of which are now fixed, some of which have fixes in hand and are proving to be a tedious manual process to get past and some are down to simply user training. However one of the issues (requests from management) is tripping me up.

The flows are divided into 3 parts. The first flow is run by the user from within the SPO library, choosing whether the file is for review, for publish or for both.

That flow then triggers one of the other two flows behind the scenes.

1 flow does review only, the other does both review and then publish. Handling notifications, responses and updating the file accordingly at each step.

Now that all works (again, user training not withstanding) but there's a gap in the logic. It's possible to send a document for publish that has NOT been reviewed. Management have requested/instructed that the loophole should be closed (not unreasonably).

My gut instinct therefore is for the publish flow to have a check, querying the file in question to see if there's a 'last reviewed' date - if so, crack on, if not, halt and send an error back to the person who ran the flow.

What I'm struggling with is finding any good tutorials/guidance on how to query a file for specific metadata (we add 'last reviewed' to all files through a custom content type) - and then generate a custom failure/error message based on that result.

Addendum: I've managed to get somewhere - at least kind of, in the first flow I've added a clause for the 'publish only' check:
[publish only step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvLEA.png)
I'd thought 'null' would be valid, and while the flow does indeed stop, its more because of a crash than anything else.

Now researching how to reference an empty field in an SPO library...

Any pointers would be welcomed.

Comment: Got a bit further, not sure it's elegant, but it does appear to work - meant having to put a condition within a condition though. Checks for publish only (yes/no) then if Yes, checks for review date is not equal to null - if yes, fails with email notification, if no, continues onto the publish step. Next step is to make the date check more of a quantity (i.e. less than x period since review)

Answer (score 0):

Broke the logic into sequential conditional checks.

Contenttype metadata as an HTTP type rather than dynamic, is equal to expression(null)

Now works as requested.